# How to draw a point on the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am drawing the graph below

[image]

with the following code:

```
start = 0
finish = len(predictions)
pl.plot(predictions[start:finish,0], predictions[start:finish,2], 'bo', label="Predicted")
pl.plot(actual_measurements[start:finish,0], actual_measurements[start:finish,1], 'g^', label="Actual")
```

The blue circles follow the green triangles to a some point but then start diverging away. That point happens to be the last 60 blue circles (the actual predicted points).

**Question**

Is there a way I can point out on the plot where the last 60 blue circles begin?

Comment: if you change last 60 values in `actual_measurements` then last 60 points change position.

Comment: @furas I'm not clear by what you mean. Could you please elaborate

Comment: sorry I'm not clear what you mean in question.

Comment: @Anthony what do want to do, draw a point or to point out? Its not clear what you want to do. You can use `annotate` method of the plot object to 'point out' where the start is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the point where the two curves a diverging you can just plot this point again e. g. in a different color. Add this at the end of your code:

```
pl.plot(actual_measurements[finish - 60:finish - 59, 0],
        actual_measurements[finish - 60:finish - 59, 1], 'ro',
        label="Diverging")
```

If you do not know the point you need some algorithm to determine it.